# PUT request works fine, and database is updating, but I get 'Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]'

Tags: node.js

I have a put request that looks like this:

```
router.put('/employees', (req, res, next) => {
      req.body.employees.forEach((employee) => {
        Employee
        .update(
          { _id: employee._id }, 
          { $set: { totalHours: 15 } 
        })
        .exec(
          (err, doc) => {
            if (err) {
              res.status(404).send(err);
            }
            else {
              res.status(200).send(doc);
            }
          }
        )
      })
    })
```

It's supposed to update the totalHours property of each employee to 15. It works fine, except that after updating the employees I get an error (Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client) and node crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only respond to a request once.

In your case you get a request, loop over a number of employees, and then respond to the request inside the loop: i.e. once for each employee.

You need to finish your loop and then respond once.